# Unix command to get 0 count , when no files present for the day along with count

Tags: awk, files, find

How to do I get the list days were no files been received. Have used the below command to get the file count along with the date:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | awk '{array[$0]+=1}END{ for(val in array) print val" "array[val]   }'|sort
```

Output:

```
2019-05-09 1
2019-05-10 3
2019-05-13 2
2019-05-14 5
2019-05-15 1
2019-05-16 2
2019-05-17 1
2019-05-20 2
```

I would need the missing days count as 0 as well. For eg:

```
2019-05-12 0
```

Comment: Instead of looping over files in a directory, you should loop over the dates and check if a corresponding file is there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
TIME_STAMP=(`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td\n' | sort | sed -e 1b -e '$!d'`)
LIST ()
{
        date1=$1
        date2=`date -d "$date1 + 1 day" +"%Y-%m-%d"`
        find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt $date1 ! -newermt $date2 | echo "$date1 `wc -l` "
        [ $date1 == $2 ] && exit 0;
        LIST $date2 $2
}
LIST ${TIME_STAMP[0]} ${TIME_STAMP[1]}
```

Comment: Thanks ,  this provides the required output. I will sort the output as per the required format.

Answer (score 0):

```
date0='20190501'
date1='20190622'
numDays=$(( ( $(date -d "$date1" +'%s' ) - $(date -d "$date0" +'%s' ) ) / (60*60*24) ))
for day in $( seq 0 $((numDays-1)) ); do
  d=$(date -d "$date0 + ${day}days" +"%Y-%m-%d")
  echo $d $( find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "$d"  ! -newermt "$d + 1day" | grep '.' -c )
done
```

Get number of days by difference between `date0` and `date1`, loop each day and print found result.

**xarg version**

```
date0='20190501'
date1='20190622'
seq 0 $(( ( $(date -d "$date1" +'%s' ) - $(date -d "$date0" +'%s' ) ) / (60*60*24) )) \
  | head -n -1 \
  | xargs -I{} date -d "$date0 + {}days" +%Y%m%d \
  | xargs -I{1} bash -c 'echo {1} $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt "{1}" ! -newermt "{1} + 1day" | grep "." -c)'
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, have received the below mentioned error. Could you please help with the same:
syntax error near unexpected token `('
`comm -23 <(seq 0 $((numDays-1)) | xargs -I{} date -d "$date0 + {}day" +"%Y-%m-%d") \'

Comment: Method changed, see update.